# DocuSign callback envelope XML schema is different from the one received on consuming DocuSign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

The envelope XML that is received from DocuSign callback is in below format:

```
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
<EnvelopeStatus>
    <RecipientStatuses>
        <RecipientStatus>
            <Type>
```

The one received on consuming DocuSign Envelopes Get API `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/<AccountId>/envelopes/<envolopeId>?include=recipients, tabs&advanced_update=true` is:

```
<envelope>
<allowMarkup>false</allowMarkup>
<allowReassign>true</allowReassign>
<allowViewHistory>true</allowViewHistory>
.
.
<recipients>
    <agents/>
    <carbonCopies>
        <carbonCopy>
            <customFields
             .
             .
```

There are occasion where we lose callback information and hence thinking of developing polling mechanism to bring those envelopes in sync. Now, since both the envelope XML (have data that we need) their XML format are completely different.

Is there any specific DocuSign API (I searched entire API libraries and couldnt find one) that will give the envelope XML similar to one that received via a callback? Or is there different approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get XML you will need to use SOAP API, but I'm not sure why you need XML. The important thing is getting the information inside the JSON/XML, the format shouldn't matter.

I would also strongly advise not to use polling as it may increase your API usage and eventually you may go above your limit.

DocuSign Connect webhook has a retry mechanism so it will try to call you again if your endpoint was down for any reason. Not sure what other reasons you may not be getting your callbacks, but I'll research a solution to the root cause instead of doing polling.

Comment: Thank you @InbarGazit. We will give SOAP based API a try. And yes you are absolutely right on the concerns. Callback mechanism will continue to be our primary mode to process all the envelopes. And also we did see fault tolerance being provided by the DocuSign and it should take care of most of the scenarios. Here we are referring to outliers that shoudn't be more than 0.1% of the envelopes. The current plan is to run the polling process once in 24 hours and would ensure all the checks and balances are in place as per DocuSign API guidelines.

Comment: you can also change from XML to JSON on the callback information from the webhook